# How to update a widget textview from the value from next activity

Tags: android

I have a widget with a textview and a button.If i clik on the button it will go to next activity, where you can set the value for the textview in the widget. I am able to move to next activity using "PendingIntent" , but i cant update the widget textview.
Can anyOne help?

Comment: Can you update the code where you put all these...

Comment: put Question with your actual error and some code that you have written

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findResourceById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
TextView.setText("Your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Actually, you should not use the PendingIntent. You will be use the intent to start the next activity.

First Activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(Firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
in.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(in);
```

Second Activity

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String imagename = in.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

use startActivityforResult and onActivityResult methods.